# Instagram API permission review

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

On the form you submit to request permissions, they have an option they deem valid: "My app allows people to login with Instagram and share their own content.
". You then go on the explain what your app does. However, I don't see how this is possible, since the only endpoints available are all GETs, you can't post (share) anything. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood *share* word meaning in this context. *Sharing* does not mean *posting*. It means that you help the users to share their own content by the features of your app, such as creating widget that they can embed (share) on their own website.

Comment: Thanks makes, sense. Would you have a good example of an app that does this?

Comment: @JimLayhey you can try to look for Instagram widgets like https://lightwidget.com/  https://snapwidget.com/ etc. They are using Instagram API for sure:)